# IF condition inside FOR loop in batch

Tags: batch-file

Refer to [check "IF" condition inside FOR loop (batch/cmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163938/check-if-condition-inside-for-loop-batch-cmd)

My batch

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('findstr /c:"B1" text.txt') do (
    if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
        echo B1 found
    ) else (
        echo B1 NOT found
    )
)
```

If my `text.txt` file contains `B1;123` (which mean B1 string found), `B1 found` message appear on the screen. but if my `text.txt` file contains `A;123` (wwhich mean B1 string not found), `B1 NOT found` message not appear on the screen.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. 
thank you very much.

Comment: If the string is not found the IN clause is empty.  The FOR command does not process empty or blank lines.  You do not need to wrap your FINDSTR command into a FOR command.  Just do the FINDSTR and then test the errorlevel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access the return code of a command executed by FOR /F because the command is executed in a new cmd.exe session.

But if all you want to do is detect if the file contains the string or not, then there is no need for a FOR /F loop:

```
findstr /c:"B1" text.txt >nul && echo B1 found || echo B1 not found
```

***Update in response to comment***

The FOR /F loop returns ERRORLEVEL 1 if no rows are iterated. It leaves ERRORLEVEL unchanged if at least one row is iterated. You must surround the entire loop in parentheses if you want to use `||` as I do. Also, you must guarantee that the last command within the loop succeeds, which is what `(call )` does (it sets ERRORLEVEL to 0).

```
@echo off
(
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /c:"B1" text.txt') do (
    set "str=%%A"
    echo B1 found
    (call )
  )
) || echo B1 not found
```

Or you could use the variable to determine whether there were any iterations

```
@echo off
set "str="
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /c:"B1" text.txt') do (
  set "str=%%A"
)
if defined str (echo B1 found) else echo B1 not found
```

Comment: Thank you @dbenham. your script work for me.
but, sometime i want to save string found in the text file.
how to save string found in the text file?

`findstr /c:"B1" text.txt >nul && >>result.txt || echo B1 not found > fail.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

Again it's `delayedexpansion`. Within a `for` loop, any `%variablename%` is replaced by the actual value of the variable at the time that the `for` is encountered, so `%errorlevel%` will be replaced by the value of `errorlevel` at that time - probably 0.

To access the value of `errorlevel` as it is changed *within* the loop, use the conventional syntax

```
if errorlevel n (dothis) else (dothat)
```

which means "is the current value of `errorlevel` is n **or is greater than n**

hence, replace the `if` with

```
if not errorlevel 1 ...
```

or better reverse and reformat to avoid a double-negative
although, as squishy says, since your `findstr` will return *nothing* for a not-found condition, the `for` loop has nothing to process, so the `else` clause wouldn't be reached - even if it was legally constructed.

Comment: Nope. Delayed expansion can't help here ;-) See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40275833/1012053)

Comment: @dbenham : certainly, as I remarked in my last paragraph. There are two problems - expecting `%var%` to be evaluated within a block ("delayedexpansion") and expecting the loop to be executed in the 'not found' condition.