# check for spaces in file name inside of for loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that is calling a VBscript file. It reiterates through all files in a watched folder.

It needs to verify if the file name has spaces in it and if so reject the file and not process it with the VBS.

I must have an error on the code as I get the error message:

> ELSE was not expected at this time.

I have looked at the documentation and searched for the answer for quite some time, including this question: [check "IF" condition inside FOR loop (batch/cmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163938/check-if-condition-inside-for-loop-batch-cmd)

But still, I can't see what is wrong in my syntax:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call :ReadIni Infolder inFolder 
call :ReadIni Outfolder outFolder 

echo %inFolder%
echo %outFolder%

pause

:StartLoop
FOR %%I in (%inFolder%\*.srt) DO (
  ECHO %%I
  ECHO %%~nxI
  SET TESTNAME=%%~nxI
  ECHO !TESTNAME!
  ECHO !TESTNAME: =_!
  PAUSE
  IF NOT !TESTNAME!==!TESTNAME: =_! (
    move "%~sdp0%%~nxI" "%outFolder%\ERROR_IN_FILE_NAME_%%~nxI"
  ) ELSE (
    copy /y "%%I" "%~sdp0%%~nxI"
    %~sdp0SRToffset.vbs "%~sdp0%%~nxI" "%~sdp0%%~nxI"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
      Goto StartLoop
    ) else (
      move "%~sdp0%%~nxI" "%outFolder%\"
      move "%~sdp0QC_%%~nxI" "%outFolder%\"
      del "%%I"
    )
  )
)
timeout /t 1
goto StartLoop

:ReadIni
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('find "%~1=" config.ini') do set %~2=%%a
exit /b
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF NOT "!TESTNAME!"=="!TESTNAME: =_!" (

 ...

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
```

Quoting the strings causes `cmd` to regard the string as a single entity.

Note that the following `if %errorlevel%` will be executed using the value of `errorlevel` at `:startloop`. (See `delayed expansion` for reasoning.)

Cure by using `if !errorlevel!==1 (`. (Using the runtime value of `errorlevel` as established by the `vbs` routine.)

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out, too. This is what I ended up using `IF "!TESTNAME!" NEQ "!TESTNAME: =_!" (` and thanks for pointing out the error in **errorlevel**. I changed it to `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (`